# UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter (UICollectionViewController StoryBoard)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have researched and I don't know what is missing in my code. I have used storyboard and connected my BrowseView to UICollectionViewController and I have used a Xib file for my cell and I already set my xib file to my class.

```
   class BrowseView: UICollectionViewController {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.delegate   = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "BrowseItemCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
}

extension BrowseView {

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BrowseItemCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create it in code UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, 
collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

or if CollectionView just one of the elements in your ViewController that's should looks in this way

```
 let newCollection: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let collection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collection.isScrollEnabled = true
    return collection
 }()
```